# external hyperlinks in python comments (""")

Tags: python, github, hyperlink, markdown, comments

Can I embed a markdwon-style url link inside a python comment?

```
def func():
    """
    see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/)
    """
```

I want this link to be visible + usable when viewed in a browser in a GitHub repo. Is it doable?

Comment: How github deals with URLs in code is more of a github question than a Python question.